# Why this SVG image from sprite-sheet is not getting rendered in HTML but not in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, webpack

I have this code for SVG sprite

```
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 22 22" id="github">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="a" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 436 428">
        <image width="436" height="428" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,.........."></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="11" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M0 0h22v22H0z"></path>
</symbol>
```

The GithHub icon is perfectly rendered with HTML code,

```
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#github"></use>
</svg>
```

When I use React.JS the icon is not getting displayed.

**icons2.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 22 22" id="github">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="a" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 436 428">
            <image width="436" height="428" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."></image>
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="11" fill="#fff"></circle>
        <path fill="url(#a)" d="M0 0h22v22H0z"></path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
    </svg>
```

**App.tsx**

```
import icons from './icons2.svg';
let five = 'github';

class App extends Component {
 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <svg>
                  <use href={`${icons}#${five}`} />
               </svg>
           </div>
        );
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit ?

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Components with hardcoded id values are a footgun.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Create React App you can do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as ReactSprite } from "./icons.svg";
let five = "github";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactSprite />
      <svg>
        <use href={`#${five}`} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If not, you would need to install [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) and use it as a webpack loader.

[image: Edit ecstatic-butterfly-4wdym]

Comment: Some images are getting rendered following this approach, some are not.

Comment: It's hard to know what could be the problem without knowing exactly what was in the svgs in question.